# Saving data using promises

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, promise

On Parse.com I have the following function, and my question follows:

```
function myFunction(array, value) {
    var logMessage;
    logMessage = "array: " + array.length.toString();
    console.log(logMessage);

    if (!array.length) return;
    if (!value) value = Math.min(10, array.length);
    if (array[array.length - 1].get("advertisePointNumber") >= value) return;

    var classPromise;

    array[array.length - 1].set("advertisePointNumber", value);

    logMessage = "(BIS)array: " + array.length.toString();
    console.log(logMessage);

    classPromise = (array[array.length - 1].save(null, {}).then(function (object) {
        logMessage = "HERE I AM!!!";
        console.log(logMessage);
        if (array.length == 1) return;
        array.splice(array.length - 1, 1);
        return myFunction(array, value);
    }, function (error) {
        // saving the object failed.
        console.log("error:" + error);
    }));

    logMessage = "(TER)array: " + array.length.toString();
    console.log(logMessage);

    return Parse.Promise.when(classPromise);
}
```

The question is what am I missing? I never see the message "HERE I AM!!!" (and no error either) in the logs and as a consequence the recursive call that I wish is not working.

I have successfully used similar code in the past, when reading data. Here I am saving data. I must be doing something the wrong way. What is it?

Update to the question:

Calling this function with the following line of code:

```
myFunction(myArray, 0);
```

I get the log below:

```
I2015-06-22T07:05:34.160Z]myArray: 2  // Number of elements in the initial Array.

I2015-06-22T07:05:34.161Z]array: 2

I2015-06-22T07:05:34.162Z](BIS)array: 2

I2015-06-22T07:05:34.163Z](TER)array: 2
```

I would expect to see :

```
I2015-06-22T07:0.....]array: 1
```

after the above but I do not see anything.

Comment: can you post what log you are getting, like `array:...;(BIS)arr...`

Comment: I just edited the question, to provide what you need. I hope it can help.

Comment: what happens when you try `array[array.length - 1].save().then(fu...`

Comment: You mean removing : null,{} ?
I commented it out and it does not change.

Comment: @Michel see the answer below

Comment: @Michel what do you mean by recursive, do you want everything in the array to be saved?

Comment: If you look inside myFunction you will see that there is a call to myFunction. It is meant to save the following element in the array. This call does not happen, this is the problem I have.
Yes I want everything in the array to be saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going for recursive, you can try this:

```
classPromise = array.map(function(obj){ return obj.save();});
```

in es6, same thing can be:

```
classPromise = array.map(obj => obj.save());
```

**Edit**

You can reduce the whole function to:

```
function myFunction(array, value) {

    if ( !array  || !array.length) return;
    console.log("array: " + array.length);
    if (!value) value = Math.min(10, array.length);
    var pSave=[], i = array.length, v2=(value)? value : Math.min(10, i);

    while(i>0 && array[i-1].get("advertisePointNumber") >= value){
        array[i - 1].set("advertisePointNumber", value);
        pSave.push(array[i - 1].save());
        console.log("(BIS)array: " + i);
        i--;
        v2=(value)? value : Math.min(10, i);
    }

    return Parse.Promise.when(pSave);
}
```

if you wanted it to be saved sequentially,

```
    ...
    var pSave = Parse.Promise.as(1),
    ...
    pSave.then(function(){
        return array[i-1].save();
    });
    ...

    return pSave;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works, saving the whole array. I am still curious about why my code did not work though. I had never used map before, I need to check if it guaranties any order in the saving process. If my understanding of promises is correct, what I was trying to do would guaranty the order.

Comment: @Michel you can use to option2 to ensure sequential

Comment: Thanks for this code, it is very useful to help me better understand promises.

Comment: What is the meaning of 1 ? in the line: var pSave = Parse.Promise.as(1),
Is it the maximum index of the array?

Comment: I am not sure I entirely see  what you mean by what is written after :
"if you wanted it to be saved sequentially,"

Comment: My knowledge of promises is still too limited to be 100% confident on how to interpret ... in option2. I can only guess the idea.

Comment: Promise.as just gives a promise which  resolves to value 1. PSave. Push  does not guarantee that it would be  saved in  order but PSave. then does guarantee the order

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to pass `null` as the 1st parameter
2. You don't need to use both `save` with options (2nd parameter), and `save` with promises chain (.then)

So, just remove both the first and the second parameter of `save` function as follows

```
array[array.length - 1].save().then(...
```

> Updated Answer

You should use multiple `save` calls in promises chain instead of recursive one like the below

```
function myFunction(array, value) {
    var logMessage;
    logMessage = "array: " + array.length.toString();
    console.log(logMessage);

    if (!array.length) return;
    if (!value) value = Math.min(10, array.length);

    var savePromises = Parse.Promise.as();

    array.map(function(element, index) {

        // Calculate value based on your needs
        if(element.get("advertisePointNumber") < value) {
            element.set("advertisePointNumber", value);
        }

        savePromises = savePromises.then(function() {
            return element.save();
        });

    });

    return savePromises.then(function (object) {
            logMessage = "HERE I AM!!!";
            console.log(logMessage);
        }, function (error) {
            // saving the object failed.
            console.log("error:" + error);
        });
}
```

OR if you have the option to make cloud code to save them in one request, you should do, to reduce network requests

Comment: I did that, but it still does not work any better. To be precise the first save is happening correctly, but since there is no recursive call, the following elements are not saved. Am I doing something wrong with the promises?

Comment: What's the purpose of this recursion and its intention?

Comment: It is to guaranty the order of the saving process; if my understanding of promises is correct.
If you know why it is not working please let me know.

Comment: This is a cloud function.

Comment: Thanks. The line "var savePromises = Parse.Promise.as(1);" is somewhat initializing the promise chain? Is that correct?
Promises are definitelly powerful, but not so easy :)

Comment: Yes, it creates and resolves the first promise in the promise chain

Comment: Something like `Parse.Promise.as().then(function() { return array[0].save(); }).then(function() { return array[1].save(); }).then(function() { return array[2].save(); })`

Comment: OK thanks. I am starting to understand how all this works. That said I certainly will want to optimize the code in your last comment when I have 2789 elements in my array :)